# Should I sign or print my name on a print?

Tags: prints, display

I am mounting a series of limited edition prints, below the image I have added the no (i.e 1/50) on the left , the title in the middle and my signature on the right.

But my signature could not be diciphered to work out my name. Furthermore my signature does not work as well as usual because I am wiring on satin paper and for the pen to work I need it to be more upright then I would usually do for signing. I'm wondering if I should print my name (as in write my name neatly) rather than use my standard signature ?

Comment: There are several different kinds of tips available for laying ink on paper. Some are more suitable for textured surfaces than others. There are porous tips, roller ball, and capillary tubes using a variety of pigments. Finally, signatures may be discernible or not depending on the individual. Merely writing one's name does not make it a signature as in a "signed" limited-edition print which is what you're implying. Furthermore, willfully signing your name differently, with the intent of avoiding your legal signature, is forgery.

Comment: I wasn't trying to avoid my signature because I wanted to avoid signing, I was just wondering if I should make it readable, but your advice is I should keep my ilegible signature

Comment: Try tilting the writing surface a bit to accommodate the need for a steeper writing angle for the pen nib/point. Try rotating the barrel of the pen in your grip in case the tip has a tiny irregularity. Normal writing paper is quite abrasive and would grind-off something that might otherwise catch on your paper stock.

Comment: Surely your signature is your signature whether it can be deciphered as your name or not. IE adapting it to look clearer is not the same signature. Your bank might have an issue with that when signing a cheque.

Comment: @lharby yes my signature is my signature, clearly I wouldnt chnage it if signing a cheque. But when hand writing information onto a print I dont think I would be breaking any law by writing my name instead of signing my name, the question was really which would look best.

Answer (score 1):

**Do *BOTH***

Why not do both? Print your name in the appropriate place using an attractive typeface such as Caslon, roman style, in medium weight on the type layer of your image-processing software. To get the effect you want you might even print on over-size stock to allow the name to lie comfortably on the L R/H corner of the border.

Then, scrawl your signature over, under, or through your typeset name on the print. You have the best of both worlds.

Hand-number the print #/total # in the L L/H corner

Marketing TIP: I also *STRONGLY* encourage to adopt the habit of dating your print (even if on the back). Dated work is highly desirable and valued over signed, undated work.

Additionally, you could also do a nice tasteful job "typesetting" the title that way.

Comment: THis is the date the print was made rather than the date the phorograph was taken ?

Answer (score -1):

You can prepare a combination of your name and signature.

Take a look at this google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=name+and+signature+logo

Take care on one thing: There is a chance you need to increase the resolution of the output. For example I'm fine with a 100-150 ppi output on a photo, but on text I would double that resolution; 200-300 ppi. That could be an issue on big prints.

Watch what resampling algorthm you use. Probably use nearest neibourg.

Or use a vector based program to prepare the output, this way you do not touch the resolution of the photo.

Comment: I think he's asking about physically writing on each print, not making his signature a part of the image to be printed.

Comment: "I'm wondering if I should print my name" It clearly says **Print**.

Comment: @Rafael I mean physically write thats why it says in brackets (as in write my name neatly), in English print can mean to not write in joined up writing,

Comment: Oh... My bad...